# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging started support for microsoft edge?

Tags: firebase, browser, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, push

I am able to generate token for chrome and firefox using below code but getting errors for Edge.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
return messaging.getToken();
})
.then(function(token) {
console.log(token); 
}
})
.catch(function(err) { 
console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);

})
```

[FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOKsH.jpg)

Comment: Care to add more details, like the errors you receive?

Comment: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK  --------- I am getting this error in console